# Help on Open source controls in commercial application

Tags: open-source, components

What are the implications of including a set of visual components released under a [Mozilla Public License](http://www.mozilla.org/MPL/MPL-1.1.html) in a commercial application.

Do I have any obligations?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found pretty good analysis on MPL (and others) by Frank Hecker here:

http://hecker.org/writings/setting-up-shop (search for "Mozilla Public License")

This pretty much sums it up:

> For MozPL-ed source code considered as
>   a set of source files, modifications
>   of the original source files are
>   considered to also fall under the
>   MozPL, as are new source files
>   incorporating extracts from the
>   original source files. Such modified
>   or new files are required to be
>   licensed under the same terms as the
>   original files, and in particular must
>   be made freely and publicly available
>   in source form.

...

> Thus an open-source product initially
>   released under the MozPL may be
>   extended with proprietary code to
>   create new proprietary products, as
>   long as the proprietary code is
>   separate (i.e., in separate files) and
>   interacts with the open-source code
>   using a defined API.

But as usual, read it carefully and consult your lawyers.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem is if you modify the components you must release them under Mozilla Public License as well